Signature Schemes in Multiuser setting
The security of signature schemes in single user setting is expected to satisfy existential unforgeability under a chosen message attack (EUF-CMA). The following paper has given the notion of security of signature schemes in multi-user settings 1. The paper considers EUF-CMA and key substitution attacks to ensure the scheme is secure in multi user settings.
Are there any further improvements over the following definitions of security of multi-user signature schemes? Is it enough to ensure security concerning key substitution attacks? Are there any ways to attack signatures in multi-user scenario?
I cannot visualize why some schemes like RSA-FDH cannot be proven secure using the definition of multi-user signature schemes.
